# Open Notepad and add Text not working

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I just saw this snippet from the internet but it doesn't work from me.
It's suppose to open a new notepad application and add "asdf" into it.

Is there any wrong on the code?

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]     
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lParam);

void Test()
{
         const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process notepad = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
    SendMessage(notepad.MainWindowHandle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "asdf");
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work for me" - Well, what _does_ it do?  Does a `notepad.exe` process start?  Is the Notepad application displayed?  Is there any error from any of this code?  You say that you "saw this snippet from the internet" but do you understand what it's doing?  For example, what is the purpose of that `const`?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Does notepad open?

Comment: I was trying to open a new notepadd then add some text. from the code above it's "asdf"

Comment: no error, it's text not being added once the notepad has been opened

Answer (score 4):

To make sure that process is ready to accept input, call `notepad.WaitForInputIdle()`. And it is important to use `MainWindowHandle` of the process that was just created, not the any notepad process.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

static void ExportToNotepad(string text)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad");
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    Process notepad = Process.Start(startInfo);
    notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

    IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), null, null);
    SendMessage(child, 0x000c, 0, text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Code will do the trick for you,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process [] notepads=Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        if(notepads.Length==0)return;            
        if (notepads[0] != null)
        {
            IntPtr child= FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
            SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
        void Test()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process notepad = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
            //Wait Until Notpad Opened
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Process[] notepads = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepads[0].MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
            SendMessage(child, 0x000c, 0, "test");
        }
```