# WPF Create a txt file from a byte array in memory and open it with notepad

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Someone told me that if you end up on the Google 3rd page on all of your searches is almost impossible to do it, but this should be very simple.
I am receiving a byte array from WCF and I would like to convert it to a txt file. The thing is that i would like to open them using a button in WPF without writing a copy of that file on the client side hard-drive. If it is necessary the user can save it locally from notepad directly.
All the files are very small(up to 100kb) so RAM should not be affected.
Thank you for all of your answers! I will post the result here in case someone need it in the future!
_______________________________________________________________________________
Create a new class: NotePadHelper(include System.Runtime.InteropServices;)

```
public class NotePadHelper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowText")]
    private static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

    public static void ShowMessage(string message = null, string title = null)
    {
        Process notepad = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe"));
        if (notepad != null)
        {
            notepad.WaitForInputIdle();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
                SetWindowText(notepad.MainWindowHandle, title);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                IntPtr child = FindWindowEx(notepad.MainWindowHandle, new IntPtr(0), "Edit", null);
                SendMessage(child, 0x000C, 0, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you need to convert the byte array to string and show the Doc in Notepad

```
var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(docObject.Image);
                NotePadHelper.ShowMessage(str, docObject.Name);
```

Thank you @keyboardP and @PInvoke!

Comment: Try using the PInvoke answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14295249/187697), I believe that's what you're asking for

Comment: Thank you. I need to work on it, because this function take the message as a string and not as a byte array.

Comment: Have a look at `MemoryMappedFile`

Comment: @AlexandruFlorin As your question was a duplicate, and you've copied the answer from another question verbatim, I've closed your question as duplicate. For future reference, though: instead of editing your question to include an answer, you should instead answer your own question (and mark your own answer as correct).

Comment: @DanPuzey I understand. The way i said it was different but the functionality was the same. I am not looking for any reward so the edit is fine. :) Thanks again for all the people which helped me.

Comment: @AlexandruFlorin It's not about whether you're looking for reward; it's about preserving the functionality of the site for other users. That's why answers should be posted as answers, not as edits to questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This truly can be done. Its just a bit of work.
First you need to get a string of your `byte[]`.
This is quite easy:

```
string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```

Now all you need to do is to open `Notepad` and write that text to it...

So what happens in many common programs a local copy is created in background to prevent potential dataloss.

I would **suggest** doing the same. Just write to a file (in temp dir), save the path and open it.

```
//To Save to a file:
string tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
File.WriteAllText(tempPath, text);
//Now open the file you just created:
Process.Start(tempPath);
```

Assuming the user is saving it on a different path you're free to delete the temp file.

**If you wanna try the thing with writing into notepad here's a link on where to get so details:**

[Open Notepad and add Text not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304755/open-notepad-and-add-text-not-working)

I dislike working with handles and manipulating other windows but feel free to give it a try.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just a side note, the OP will need to use the encoding originally used to encode the source string to a byte array (you've assumed UTF8 which may, or may not be right).

Comment: OP did originally state "without writing a copy of that file on the client side hard-drive." Although you're only using a temporary file, you aren't meeting that requirement.

Comment: I just noted some additional ways to do it ? I also gave input on how to do it without a local/temp copy ?!

Comment: Thank you @Nudity! As Dan Puzey said i don't want to write anything on the hard disk, but i really appreciate your help. I just checked that on small project and your solution is working.